# set multiple filter on powershell azure commands

Tags: azure, powershell

i try to get all the members users who are have account disabled in the same command.

this one works :

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true -filter "(UserType eq 'Member')"
```

this one also works :

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true -filter "(AccountEnabled eq false)"
```

but not this one :

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true -filter {"(UserType eq 'Member')" -and "(AccountEnabled eq false)"}
```

so what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I would give it a try with a lighter syntax since this has to be considered as a single OData query (meaning no ```-and``` which is here a mix between PS syntax and the actual command in use).
Something like : ```Get-AzureADUser -All $true -filter "UserType eq 'Member' and AccountEnabled eq false"```

Comment: Lovely ! Adding as an answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give it a try with a lighter syntax since this has to be considered as a single OData query (meaning no ````-and``` within the query which is here a mix between PS syntax and the actual command in use).

See [OData queries description](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/#queryingcollections) - which is what is used under the hood by `Get-AzureADUser -filter`

So in this case : `Get-AzureADUser -All $true -filter "UserType eq 'Member' and AccountEnabled eq false"`